# Fastest way to get the max date in SQL database (Azure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table that has Many rows up to 1000000. and 300 columns

Question : I would like to know the fastest way to get the max date of the column 'LastModifiedDate in table.

In My table I have the columns :  **Id**, **LastModifiedDate** and others columns...

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inserted records are the latest `LastModifiedDate`  and this `LastModifiedDate` column will not change after being written into the table.
I think you can create a **Clustered index** on the `LastModifiedDate` column. In a Clustered table, a SQL Server clustered index is used to store the data rows sorted based on the clustered index key values. You can referance this documentation [Designing effective SQL Server clustered indexes](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-effective-sql-server-clustered-indexes/).

Comment: This would probably move the row every time the LastModifiedDate was changed. So would depend on the application if this is a good idea or not.

Comment: Yes, if the inserted records are the latest date and this date will not change after being written into the table, this will be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Put an index on the column and use:

```
select max(LastModifiedDate)
from t;
```

If you want the complete row with the largest date:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
order by LastModifiedDate desc;
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a fastest way please

Comment: @hugo . . . With an index, this should be the fastest way.